# Python encoding for Swedish characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mysql-python

I'm using scrapy to extract data from a web site. I'm saving the data to a mysql database using MysqlDB. The script works for English sites, but when I try it on a Swedish site I get:

```
self.db.query(insertion_query)
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 156:      
ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have put the following line at the top of each file involved in the scraping process to indicate the use of international charachters:
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

But I still get an error. What else do I need for python to accept non-english charachters? Here's the full stack trace:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.3-py2.7-win32.egg\scrapy\middleware.py",    
      line 60, in _process_
      chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.3-py2.7-win32.egg\scrapy\utils\defer.py",    
      line 65, in process_
      chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 368, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 464, in  
      _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\tco\tco\pipelines.py", line 64, in process_item
        self.db.query(insertion_query)
     exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 156:  
     ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: do yourself a favor and actually read this : http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html - it will only save you time.

Comment: What database wrapper are you using?

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers...I've added the full stack trace to the questions now. I have read the documentation at docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html but still can't figure it out...I'm using MysqlDB to connect, and it works with englisg sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This unicode issue look confusing at first, but it's actually pretty easy.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
```

If you write this on top of your source code, It means, python is going to
treat your code as utf-8, but not incoming or outgoing data.

You obviously want to write some data to your database, and this error happens
when some of your module encoding your utf-8 string (which is I guess swedish) to ascii.

That means, either MySQL was set as ascii or your mysql db driver is set as ascii.

So I suggest go check your mysql setting or driver setting.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=database_host ,user=user ,passwd=pass,db=database_name, charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True)
```

This will make your mysql driver connect to mysql server using utf8

Comment: Thank's! Very instructive! I will check this immediately!

Comment: db = MySQLdb.connect(host=database_host ,user=user ,passwd=pass,db=database_name, charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True)
This will help you connect your mysql driver using utf8, but you still have to set your mysql server using utf8

Comment: Ok, just tried this, but I get: TypeError: 'use_unicode' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Her's my insert code: import _mysql 
        self.db=_mysql.connect(host="host",user="user_name", 
                          passwd="pass",db="test_db", charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True)

Comment: Oh... could you try using MySQLdb instead of _mysql? cause _mysql is kind low level function, and MySQLdb is a wrapper around _mysql.

Comment: Or you can do something like.
db.set_character_set('utf8')

Comment: Hmm, I just tried using MySQLdb but I run into indenattaion problems. I will have to do change the script more carefully, but I'm sure I will get it to work if I just give it some time. Thank's for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://www.harelmalka.com/?p=81) contains a hint: When creating the connection (either using `PooledDB` or `MySQLdb.connect`), specify the options `charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True`